# Only zero the bytes counter of marked chain in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I have two chians:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 68688 packets, 12M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  146 54635 MARK       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:6532 MARK set 0xfffc 
  146 54635 MARK       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:6532 MARK set 0x5
```

When I `iptables -t mangle -m connmark --mark 0x5 -Z` it will zero both 0xfffc and 0x5's counter, how to only reset the 0x5 chain's bytes counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the rule by number seems to work, i.e.

```
iptables --table mangle --zero OUTPUT 2
```

The following should give you the rule number(s) of rules matching a certain regex:

```
iptables --numeric --line-numbers --table mangle --list OUTPUT | grep 0x5 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: No way to use mark id to zero it?

Comment: Only by finding what the rule number is; I've added a possible approach in my answer.